# Sharepoint List to Org Chart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visio

I need to create an Org Chart for my department. Is it possible to use a customized SP list and then that will automatically be linked to Visio for Org Chart and refreshes each time I update the list?

We are using Excel right now but I'd like it to update the Visio org chart each time excel is refreshed.

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Answer (score 1):

things to consider:

> Visio Services in SharePoint Server 2013 can render diagrams created
>   in Visio 2010 or Visio 2013.
>
> Visio diagrams created in Visio 2010 must be created using Visio 2010
>   Professional or Visio 2010 Premium and must be published to a
>   SharePoint site as a Visio Web drawing (*.vdw) file. Standard Visio
>   2010 diagrams (.vsd files) are not rendered by Visio Services and
>   require Visio 2010 to be viewed.
>
> Visio diagrams created in Visio 2013 must be created by using Visio
>   Professional 2013. The new standard diagram format in Visio
>   Professional 2013 (*.vsdx files) can be rendered by Visio Services,
>   along with the Web drawing (.vdw) format. We recommend that you use
>   the new .vsdx format unless you require compatibility with previous
>   versions of Visio.

and also not forgetting:

> •SharePoint Server lists that are hosted on the same farm

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee663485.aspx

its possible, you can find out here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7adafdbd-dafb-4818-8b6f-22326c396e54/creating-a-chart-using-visio?forum=sharepointadminprevious

if that is not what your looking for and dont mind not doing it in visio than you can create your own webpart that connects to a list, from that list set the data in an array and populate the chart.

somthing on the lines of:

```
    private void getSurveyGraphResultForAll(string _ListName, string _SiteName, string _ViewName, Panel BODY)
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_SiteName))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {

                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ListName))
                    {
                        SPList list = null;
                        try
                        {
                            list = web.Lists[_ListName];

                            SPUser currentUser = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;

                            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();

                            string[] x = null;
                            int[] y = null;
                            int i = 0;


                                        Chart1 = new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart();
                                        Random rnd = new Random();
                                        Chart1.CssClass = "ChartLayout";
                                        Chart1.Width = 512;
                                        Chart1.Height = 396;
                                        Chart1.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;
                                        Chart1.ID = rnd.Next().ToString();

                                        Chart1.RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag;
                                        string imagespath = "/chartimages/";
                                        Chart1.ImageLocation = imagespath + "ChartPic_#SEQ(200,30)" + rnd.Next().ToString();
                                        Chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
                                        Title t = new Title(list.Title, Docking.Top, new System.Drawing.Font("Trebuchet MS", 14, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold), System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105));
                                        Chart1.Titles.Add(list.Title);


                            foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
                            {
                                foreach (SPField field in item.Fields)
                                {
                                    if (field.TypeAsString == "Choice")
                                    {



                                        if (Chart1.Series.FindByName(field.Title) == null)
                                        {                                                //.Label = field.Title;
                                            Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(field.Title);

                                        }

                                        SPFieldChoice fd = (SPFieldChoice)field;

                                        x = new string[fd.Choices.Count];
                                        y = new int[fd.Choices.Count];
                                        i = 0;

                                        foreach (string str in fd.Choices)
                                        {
                                            Chart1.Series.Add(str);
                                            SPQuery responseQuery = new SPQuery();

                                            responseQuery.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=" + field.InternalName.ToString() + " /><Value Type=\"Choice\">" + str + @"</Value></Eq></Where>";

                                            x[i] = str;
                                            y[i] = list.GetItems(responseQuery).Count;
                                            i++;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            }

                            Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);

                            Chart1.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
                            Chart1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);
                            Chart1.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
                            Chart1.BorderWidth = 2;
                            Chart1.Series[0].LabelFormat = "LabelsAngleStep30";

                            // Set pie labels to be outside the pie chart          
                            this.Chart1.Series[0]["PieLabelStyle"] = "Outside";           
                            // Set border width so that labels are shown on the outside         
                            this.Chart1.Series[0].BorderWidth = 1;          
                            this.Chart1.Series[0].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(26, 59, 105);           
                            // Add a legend to the chart and dock it to the bottom-center         
                            this.Chart1.Legends.Add("Legend1");          
                            this.Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;         
                            this.Chart1.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;        
                            this.Chart1.Legends[0].Alignment = System.Drawing.StringAlignment.Center;      
                            // Set the legend to display pie chart values as percentages        
                            // Again, the P2 indicates a precision of 2 decimals         
                            this.Chart1.Series[0].LegendText = "#PERCENT{P2}";           
                            // By sorting the data points, they show up in proper ascending order in the legend 
                            this.Chart1.DataManipulator.Sort(PointSortOrder.Descending, Chart1.Series[0]); 





                            foreach (Series a in Chart1.Series)
                            {
                                a.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
                                a.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;

                            }

                            foreach (ChartArea a in Chart1.ChartAreas)
                            {
                                a.AxisX.IsMarksNextToAxis = false;
                                a.AxisX.Interval = 1;
                                a.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
                            }

                            BODY.Controls.Add(Chart1);


                        }
                        catch (Exception a)
                        {
                            //catch exception
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ax)
                {
                    //catch exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

there is prob a better way to do it but the above works! its gettings the sharepoint survey questions and answers, then displays it within a pie chart .... you can change it to what ever chart you want! it will update every page load from the given list!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to use 3rd party SharePoint Org Chart. I would recommend [Plumsail Organization Chart](http://plumsail.com/sharepoint-orgchart) which I developed. There are also other 3rd party web part [TeamImprover SharePoint Org Chart](http://www.sharepointorgchart.com).

Comment: Please do not link to your own employers product without disclosure!

Comment: Thank you for advice, I added some details. I just want to recommend the product which I'm sure.